# Exponent code, i don't understad code behaviour

Tags: javascript

This is the code for exponent compute:

```
var exponent = function(a, n){
  if(n === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return a * exponent(a, n-1)
  }
};

console.log(exponent(5,3));
```

I don't understand this line:

```
return a * exponent(a, n-1)
```

What does `exponent(a, n-1)` mean? Especially `n-1`?

Comment: This is a recursive call (a function calling itself), passing as parameters `a` and `n - 1`

Comment: try googling `js recursive function`

Comment: I know that is a recursive function, but I don't know what `n - 1` does in the code

Comment: it removes 1 to n at each recursive call, to make sure the recursion will end someday (`if(n === 0) { return 1; }` so, you can count how much time you'll multiply `a` by itself

Comment: @LukaSale `n` is the second input of the function, `n-1` passes in the value of `n` but subtracts `1` first

Comment: This looks like recursive fibonacci sequence if I am not wrong.

Comment: That line is just saying that you can write "A to the Power N" as "A times A to the Power N minus 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), and thus it is calling itself within the function.

Let your function `exponent` be `exp` for this explanation.

Let's say you want to calculate `5^3` (five to the power of three). This is the same as writing
 `exp(5, 3)`:

`exp(5, 3)` will return `5 * exp(5, 2)`

But, we don't know what `exp(5, 2)` is yet, so we need to work that out (by using our function again)

`exp(5, 2)` will return `5 * exp(5, 1)`

Again, we don't know what `exp(5, 1)` is yet, so we also need to figure that out.

`exp(5, 1)` will return `5 * exp(5, 0)`

Once again, we still don't know what `exp(5, 0)` is, so we need to let our function calculate this. However, doing this will tirgger our *base case* as x^0 will always give you `1`. The *base case* is what allows the recursive calls to finish (as another call to a function isn't used). Thus:

`exp(5, 0)` will return `1`.

Now that we know what all our functions give, we can traverse back up our functions calls:

`exp(5, 1)` returned `5 * exp(5, 0)`, which is `5 * 1` which equals `5`

`exp(5, 2)` returned `5 * exp(5, 1)`, which is `5 * 5` which equals `25`

`exp(5, 3)` returned `5 * exp(5, 2)`, which is `5 * 25` which equals `125`

And thus, you finally get your result of:

`exp(5, 3) = 125`

Thus, the `n-1` acts somewhat like a counter, bringing you closer and closer to your base case (ie: `if(n == 0)`) and managing how many times to recursively call your function.

Answer (score 2):

In your example

`exponent(5, 3)`

On that line, it equal to

`5 * exponent(5, 2) // 2 = 3 - 1`

then, it equal to

`5 * (5 * exponent(5, 1)) // 1 = 2 - 1`

`= 5 * (5 * (5 * exponent(5, 0))) // 0 = 1 - 1`

`= 5 * (5 * (5 * 1)) // exponent(5, 0) = 1 because n === 0`

...

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function. The recursive call counts down from n to 1 by calling itself with n-1 as argument. So you get this:

```
exponent(5, 0) == 1
exponent(5, 1) == 5 * exponent(5, 1 - 1) == 5 * exponent(5, 0) == 5 * 1 == 5
exponent(5, 2) == 5 * exponent(5, 2 - 1) == 5 * exponent(5, 1) == 5 * 5 * exponent(5, 1 - 1) == 5 * 5 * exponent(5, 0) == 5 * 5 * 1 == 25
// ... and so on
```

So `n - 1` is essentially a counter, counting down the number of times the function still has to repeat itself.

Answer (score -1):

This is a recursive function for calculating `a` raised to a power `n`.  If the exponent is `0`, you're done and `1` is returned.  Otherwise a times the result of `a` raised to the power `n-1` is returned - which is recursive...

Answer (score -1):

Your function is a recursive function, lets say `a = 2` and `n = 3`,
on your first iteration, `n = 3 - 1 = 2`and `a = 2 * 2 = 4` since `n = 2 != 0`, your function iterates again,
second iteration, `n = 2 - 1 = 1` and `a =  4 * 2 = 8`
third iteration, `n = 1 - 1 = 0` since `n = 0` then it stops.