# I don't understand the recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function pow(x, n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return x;
  } else {
    return x * pow(x, n - 1);
  }
}

alert( pow(2, 3) ); // 8
```

I don't know how pow (x, n-1) works.

If we repeat it until if (n == 1), isn't the return value 2?

Comment: no, because the recursive step isn't `return pow(x, n - 1)`, it's `return x * pow(x, n - 1)`. Do you see the difference? If not, try stepping through it with a debugger, or even by hand.

Comment: https://pythontutor.com/ is a good visualizer

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan there is JS as well

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54630095/5648954) for some explanations

Comment: @cmgchess - https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html is nice! Sadly probably a bit beyond most beginners, but still really nice...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder their python visualizer is the best especially for beginners.

Comment: @cmgchess - The concept of frames seems a bit beyond a beginner, but then again, they have to learn it at some point! :-)